# iOS Md5 hash value between reading data from image file and image object are different

Tags: ios, image, md5

I want to md5 image object while i've got two different values using the below code:

```
NSString *fileName = @"1.png";    
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData *dataFromFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSData *dataFromImage = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
NSString *md5FileToString = [dataFromFile md5Hash];
NSString *md5ImageToString = [dataFromImage md5Hash];
NSLog(@"%@,%@",md5FileToString,md5ImageToString);
```

And I found the size of dataFromFile is bigger than dataFromImage's.

Comment: You created a new png file. What did you expect?

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation returns the data for the specified image in PNG format. Why the specified image  is not "1.png"?

Comment: UIImagePNGRepresentation creates a new compressed image representation from a given bitmap. Compression algorithms differ. And you are comparing hashes of different compressed image representations.